# Can you steep tea for longer in more water instead of doing multiple steepings?

Tags: tea

I make jasmine green tea sorbet… anytime I run out of the previous batch, and then use the remaining steepings of the tea to make iced tea. (Usually steep for ~10 minutes each time, starting a bit lower than the recommended temperature; at a guess this works out to compensate all the sugar and lime juice and cold temperature dulling the tea flavour.)

The tea I use is good for about 2-3 steepings this way. However, doing this in multiple steepings is a bit of faffing around I’d like to dispense with.

Is it possible, instead of using say (just shy of) an ounce of tea for four cups of water three times in a row to use a bigger pot, put the same amount of tea into three times the amount of water, and steep for longer until basically the tea is spent in one go? It’s a lot easier for me to keep the pot of water in a given temperature range than to heat it up to said range.

(What I do is I stick my Thermapen into the steam venting hole in the lid, heat up the water to say 65C, move pot to smallest burner on low, and it works out that the temperature rises by about 1C in one minute. I set a timer for five minutes, turn off the burner which makes the temperature drop at around the same rate, restart the five minutes, strain. What I want to avoid is the part where I have to keep watching the Thermapen constantly to arrive at said 65C. Maintaining the temperature afterwards means I can do whatever else until my timer beeps then run off to the kitchen for one second.)